# Вопрос про калькулятор

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил я значит создать свой калькулятор на python. Но не знаю как закончить его.

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*', ':', '^', '**']
numbers = []
operator = []
print(f'''Внимание! Внимание! Внимание!
Калькулятор поддерживает только следующие операции:
{', '.join(operators)}
''')
print('Введите выражение:')
expression = input('> ').split()

for i in expression:
    if i in operators:
        operator.append(i)
    else:
        numbers.append(i)
```

Помогите, как закончить программу, мне нужно, чтобы посчиталось значение выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_add():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "addition"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_equal():
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    
    if math == "addition":
        e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))

    if math == "subtraction":
        e.insert(0, f_num - int(second_number))

    if math == "multiplication":
        e.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))

    if math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / int(second_number))

def button_subtract():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_multiply():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_divide():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "division"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command=button_clear)

button_subtract = Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtract)
button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_multiply)
button_divide = Button(root, text="/", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_divide)

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_subtract.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_multiply.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_divide.grid(row=6, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нифига ты написал!) Я еще такого не умею) Мне пока что нужно, чтобы это через консоль работало

Comment: @ИльяФедоров не 'ты', а 'Вы'. Sorry, я через консоль не умею.

Answer (score 0):

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*', ':', '^', '**']
numbers = []
operator = []
print(f'''Внимание! Внимание! Внимание!
Калькулятор поддерживает только следующие операции:
{', '.join(operators)}
''')
print('Введите выражение:')
expression = input('> ').split()
first_number = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
second_number = int(input('Введите второе число: '))

for i in expression:
    if i in operators:
        operator.append(i)
        if i == '+':
            result = first_number + second_number
        elif i == '-':
            result = first_number - second_number
        elif i == '*':
            result = first_number * second_number
        else:
            result = first_number / second_number

    else:
        numbers.append(i)
print(f'Результат: {result}')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В Python существует функция `eval`. Она позволяет вычислять корректные выражения Python, содержащиеся в строке.

В данном случае можно использовать её:

```
print("Внимание! Калькулятор поддерживает только следующие операции: +, -, *, /, **")
print("Введите выражение:")
expression = input('> ')

print(eval(expression))
```